# Change value for animation in animateTransition using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition

I am trying to implement swipe up/down to dismiss view controller and everything is working great. If I start swiping up, it will finish the animation in the upwards direction and vice versa.

The problem appears when the user first swipes up but then decides to swipe the view controller down - how do I change the value in the animation to dismiss view controller to the bottom rather than to the top (set by the user's first swipe).

In my UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning controller I define the animation like this:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext:UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
                guard let transitionDelegate = self.transitionDelegate else {return}
                snapshot.frame.origin.y = transitionDelegate.shouldAnimateUp ? -snapshot.frame.height : snapshot.frame.height
```

TransitionDelegate points to UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition controller (where the swipe gesture is defined). ShouldAnimateUp is defined in UIPanGestureRecognizer function like this:

```
shouldAnimateUp = translatedView.center.y < translatedView.frame.height / 2
```

That is if the view is in upper half, `shouldAnimateUp = true` and the other way around. 
But unfortunately, when I call `finishInteractiveTransition()` func it uses the value which was initially set in `UIView.animateWithDuration` in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning controller when `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` was called.

So, is there any way to change values for animation in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning controller **after** `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` is called?

PS: I kind of struggled to define my problem in words (words are hard  ), so please tell me if you need additional info or if I should try to rewrite my explanation. Also, an additional hint: I would like the animation to work like image dismissal works in official Twitter app.

Comment: How are you defining `self.transitionDelegate`?  By default, it doesn't have a `shouldAnimateUp` property.  Can you share that code?

Comment: @dmorrow
My transitionDelegate is defined as such:
`protocol TransitionDelegate {
    var shouldAnimateUp: Bool {get}
}`
The delegate is UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition and the variable is defined in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning like this: `var transitionDelegate: TransitionDelegate?`

Comment: @Rob Canceling works great but I do not think it is so exceptional to swipe a little bit up and then try to dismiss the view downwards - I do it sometimes myself, really look at Twitter official app to see what I mean.

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine it. Where in the Twitter app does it do this? I'm not seeing anything like this in there.

Comment: @Rob Just open any picture and swipe up/down. Here is image when the transition underway: https://twitter.com/MarekFortCZ/status/846170217306841088

Comment: You can also DM me there to speed up the conversation if you are interested in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see what they're doing. It's actually more complicated that "if you swipe down and then up, it animates scene off upward". If you swipe down and back up, the Twitter app will cancel if you don't get much past where you started, but will go up if you pass where you started by some considerable portion (and are still swiping in that upward).

I must confess that I'm not crazy about this UX, because two very similar gestures can result in very different behavior. If you swipe down, keep your finger down, and then flick back upward, there is a seemingly arbitrary nature as to whether it's interpreted as a cancelation of the downward swipe or as an upward swipe. I personally think that if the user initiates a demonstrable downward gesture, that dragging back up should merely be a cancelation of the transition. But that's not the question here.

Anyway, if this is what you want to do, there are a couple of ways to achieve it:

1. You could consider using view property animator-based animations, which handle mid-flight changes to the animation more elegantly than older animation techniques. So, you theoretically could just [`addAnimations`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648374-addanimations) to your `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. But it seems messy to me.

   See [Advances in UIKit Animations and Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/) for more information about view property animators and how to use them with interruptible custom transitions.
2. When dismissing, you might not use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` at all. Just animate the dismissal yourself.

   For example, when you present, the `UIPresentationController` subclass can keep the presenting view (by returning `false` from [`should​Remove​Presenters​View`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipresentationcontroller/1618319-shouldremovepresentersview)). Then, when the gesture recognizer starts, it might not initiate a custom, interactive custom transition with `dismiss` at all, but instead merely adjust the `frame` of the presented scene (and modify the opacity of the dimming chrome). Then, at the end of the gesture, complete the animation manually and then the `completion` block can dismiss the presented view controller with no animation at all (because you've animated it yourself).

   IMHO, this is architecturally inelegant. A view controller has no business mucking about with chrome that should be owned by the presentation controller. But, it works.
3. We should recognize that they might not have "presented" the full screen image at all. For example, they could have done simple view controller containment, but just added the child view controller scene to the existing scene. Then, the gesture could do whatever `frame` and dimming layer opacity changes it wanted, and when its done, just do the final animation and in the completion block, just remove the child view controller (e.g. [`willMove`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmove) and [`removeFromParentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621425-removefromparentviewcontroller)).

If I were to do this, I'd probably lean towards option 3, though I'd wager that it might not feel very satisfying for you, having invested time in custom interactive transitions already. Regardless, these are a couple of approaches you could consider.

Comment: As you said, I opted for the first option because I had more or less everything set up but I will definitely think about the third one when going for a bit complicated transition animations next time. Anyway, thanks, you saved me ✌